# github web Repository blocks with : Fetching latest commit…

Tags: github

While I was editing README.md in one of my repositories, the process blocked somehow.
Since then, when I access that repository, status stays in 'Fetching latest commit… ' and I am not able to upload any files or edit them on the web.
The other repositories work. I do not have this repository on my computer (i have the files obviously), and the system does not allow me to clone it, not even delete it.
What can I do to regain access?

Comment: facing same here. seems to be a github server issue

Comment: @nikhil-mathew thank you, please tell me if/when the issue goes away for you. I can not yet access the repository.

Comment: Having the same issue on multiple of my own repositories and for friends repositories. Also the "Clone or Download" button is not working on those repositories

Comment: Seems to work again :)

Comment: Works for me too. Issue resolved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**THOUGH DEFINITELY** it does not the answer your question, but I want to post a solution for whom have the same problem but **because of different reason.**

**For Forecomers having the issue**

I had the same issue(just reached this question by googling), and I remembered disabling the javascript of my browser. Why don't you enable the javascript of your browser and refreshing the page? In my case the problem was solved after enabling javascript.